# Sortable list, sort items just between different list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In this example http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists is possible to drag and drop the items between different list and also the same list.

Will it be possible to dis-activate the drag and drop in the same list and allow just the drag and drop between different lists? how?

Comment: It's quite easy to prevent items from *drop* in the same list, however *drag* is a little tricky. How would you guess that you should not allow dragging of this element? How can you know *where* I'm going to drag current item?

Comment: @dfsq thanks for your comment. You said to me that is quite easy to prevent items from drop in the same list. sorry but I dont' understand from your question how should I do it :(

Comment: See my answer. As I said it's hard to stop dragging inside the same UL, but we can disallow dropping in the same UL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best  Ican do here:

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.item[0].parentNode == this) {
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/J6uM5/

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo** `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/UnFdU/1/

I have built a small logic behind three events, `recieve`, `start` and `stop`. Everytime if the list is same list then user cannot drop it else if different list they can, try it your self. *Little Explanation below*

- When user starts Dragging `start` says: `canDropThat = false;`
- `recieve` only gets triggered if it item is dropped from connected list, i.e. if receive is triggered make `canDropThat = true;` ; hence allow dropping.
- In the end `stop` checks for the flag and if its the right flag it allows dropping else reject.

Hope it fits the cause `:))`

**Code**

```
$(function() {
    canDropThat = false;
    var sortlists = $("#List1, #List2").sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        connectWith: '#List1, #List2',
        helper: 'original',
        scroll: true,
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            //Run this code whenever an item is dragged and dropped into this list 
            canDropThat = true;

        },
        start: function(event, ui) {
            canDropThat = false;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            if (!canDropThat) {
                $(this).sortable('cancel');
            }
        }

    }).on('scroll', function() {
        sortlists.scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    });

});​
```